# Как убрать toolbar, чтобы сохранить menu

Tags: android, kotlin, android-toolbar

У меня есть empty activity с toolbar, но я хочу убрать этот toolbar, при этом что бы осталрсь menu, возможно ли такое, я знаю что можно просто убрать toolbar, но тогда не отображается menu

Comment: [PopupMenu](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu)

Answer (score 1):

Как вы хотите сделать нельзя, но можно придумать варианты:

- Оставить тулбар и сделать его невидимым
- Как подсказали в комментарии использовать PopupMenu

Для [информации](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30417223/how-to-add-menu-button-without-action-bar) и немного про [меню](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)